# Filtering unique values from a text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to find and filter unique values from a text file.

I tried like below, its not working.

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("distinct").getOrCreate()
var data = spark.sparkContext.textFile("text/file/opath")
val uniqueval = data.map { rec => (rec.split(",")(3).distinct) }
var fils = data.filter(line => line.split(",")(3).equals(uniqueval)).map(x => (x)).foreach { println }
```

Sample Data:

```
ID | Name
1    john
1    john
2    david
3    peter
4    steve
```

Required Output:

```
1    john
2    david
3    peter
4    steve
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it right. `.distinct()` must just be called on the RDD.
I'd replace statement 3 with:

```
val uniqueval = data.distinct().map...
```

This assumes that similar records will have identical lines in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Is core scala allowed?

```
scala> val text = List ("single" , "double", "mono", "double") 
text: List[String] = List(single, double, mono, double)

scala> val u = text.distinct
u: List[String] = List(single, double, mono)

scala> val d = text.diff(u)
d: List[String] = List(double)

scala> val s = u.diff (d) 
s: List[String] = List(single, mono)
```

Answer (score 1):

your code can be something like:

```
sparkContext.textFile("sample-data.txt").distinct()
            .saveAsTextFile("sample-data-dist.txt");
```

distinct method can do the action you want.